# Jackrabbit locks up with many open ACEs

Tags: jackrabbit, aem, crx

I am running into an issue where a lot of processes block due to having more than 1000 access control entries active at a time; this is a [known issue in Jackrabbit](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-2950); a work-around has been identified and rolled out into 2.4.1, but CQ 5.5 / CRX 2.3 uses Jackrabbit 2.4.0. Are there any workarounds available under 2.4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this article that refers to CRX 2.2.  http://helpx.adobe.com/crx/kb/cacheentrycollector-cache-size-is-too-small.html

The resolution says to install CRX hotfixpack 2.2.0.56.  This makes CachingEntryCollector configurable. via a JVM parameter:

```
-Dorg.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authorization.acl.CachingEntryCollector.maxsize=10000
```

I have not been able to locate hotfix 2.2.0.56, but the solution is showing in 2.2.0.68.

This has been addressed before.  The question is, did this make it into CRX 2.3.  I am still digging through CQ, looking for org.apache.jackrabbit.core, to see if this fix made it to the new version.

**update:**
Sadly, this change did not make it in to 2.3.